# Executing a SQL*Plus .sql file in Python for Oracle Database

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

Hello everyone I have this sql file :

`Student.sql`

```
Select * from student where age > 18;

Delet student_ name , studen_id if age > 18 ;
Commit;
```

Using cx_oracle pip 
Any help

Comment: You cannot execute SQL code directly in a Python interpreter. A Python interpreter is not a SQL engine. You need to wrap it (typically in a string), and then send that string to a SQL engine to execute. There are libraries to do this like `cx_Oracle`.

Comment: I know about that but with cx_oracle I can located the .sql and execut it

Comment: Not sure what you're asking then, as your question _appears_ to be "execute .sql file in python". If you know that you can't do that, why ask it? Maybe update your question to ask what you want to know.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of executing a file, you could execute have the query defined in your code.

```
import cx_Oracle

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('Host Name', 'Port Number', service_name='Service Name') #if needed, place an 'r' before any parameter in order to address any special character such as '\'.
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'User Name', password='Personal Password', dsn=dsn_tns) #if needed, place an 'r' before any parameter in order to address any special character such as '\'. For example, if your user name contains '\', you'll need to place 'r' before the user name: user=r'User Name'
query = """
        Select * from student where age > 18;
        DeletE student_ name , studen_id if age > 18 
        """
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(query) # use triple quotes if you want to spread your query across multiple lines
print('Result', c)
#conn.close()
```

Comment: You can run the following query in Oracle to get the Service Name:
select sys_context(‘userenv’,’service_name’) from dual
You can also run the following query in Oracle to get the list of users:
select username from dba_users

Comment: Thanks so much for ur fast answer but I have 400 line code .. I just thought if there is possible to execute file .sql direct. :)

Comment: f = open("run_all_su.sql")

full_sql = f.read()

   sql_commands = full_sql.split(';')

   #sql_commands = full_sql.replace('\n', '').split(';')[:-1] # this bring just [] which is  empty

   print(sql_commands)

   for sql_command in sql_commands:

       print(sql_command)

       cur.execute(sql_command)

Answer (score 1):

As other replies noted you can only execute a statement at a time with cx_Oracle.  However you can write a wrapper to read your SQL files and execute each statement.  This is a lot easier if you restrict the SQL syntax (particularly regarding line terminators).  For an example, see https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/SampleEnv.py#L116